# Has any illegal data been saved in the Block Chain?

Tags: blockchain, legal, block

Has any [illegal data](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Weaknesses#Illegal_content_in_the_block_chain) been saved in the Block Chain, such as an [illegal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illegal_number), or [illegal prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illegal_prime)?

Comment: While seeing the Bernank's face in there is repulsive, I don't think it is criminal.  http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=BUB3dygQ

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While working on my master thesis I used the [AACS encryption key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AACS_encryption_key_controversy) (09 F9 11 02 9D 74 E3 5B D8 41 56 C5 63 56 88 C0), considered an [illegal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illegal_number), as a basis for creating a fake Bitcoin address - [1ujTAfEQh2obwdt72GrmXonakx2RxvYpX](http://blockexplorer.com/address/1ujTAfEQh2obwdt72GrmXonakx2RxvYpX). A 1 Satoshi transaction was sent to that address from address 17TQLZvXjKTrUyRnV9DuQs4RVDgNjUPeXQ. The [transaction](http://blockexplorer.com/tx/6ceb2859747dc78d6e54a35cf6b49ec8530993a864a5325cb838a765dd023618#o1) was encoded in [block 177653](http://blockexplorer.com/block/00000000000006c6076ba8b5078f6f4aafb1b55e03eddfbe2c488bc26cc723e8).

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just have the hex string 09f911029d74e35bd84156c5635688c0 be the private exponent? That makes the unused address 1KyKqNh9fM5sN8uWDLXNv2o52sqj94GhbN. (Generated using brainwallet.org)

Comment: @lurfjurv But then you are not storing the illegal number, but some derivation of it which is technically not illegal.

Comment: Oh. How does 1ujTAfEQh2obwdt72GrmXonakx2RxvYpX represent that number, then?

Comment: @lurfjurv It's hash160 (as in, hex version of the address that is a part of the block now) is 09f911029d74e35bd84156c5635688c000000000 .